# tcc in not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c, windows-7

I am trying to run a C program through a command prompt on Windows 7 but getting an error

```
tcc in not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Can you please guide me on how do i get rid from this error?

Comment: Well, did you install tcc? If you did, is it in `PATH`?

Comment: how do I install tcc?

Comment: Windows binaries are available [here](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/tinycc/).

Comment: there are too many files, which one I need to install?

Comment: Just take the latest version and if 32 bit, the win32-bin.zip.  If 64 bit, win64-bin.zip.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid from this issue, follow these steps to execute C program from command prompt on windows7

First, install tcc from [here](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/tinycc/)

Then add the path `;c:/tcc` in `PATH` like this

[image]

In the last step, go in folder where the C file exactly located by typing `cd [directoryname]` and type `tcc [filename.c]`, it will create a application or standalone file for that.